# JBPM 6 REST interface responses with 404

Tags: java, rest, jbpm

In BRMS 5 (with JBPM 5.2) when I go to the `http://localhost:8080/business-central-server/rs/server/resources/jbpm` I have listed all available methods, but in BRMS 6 there is no business-central-server application, it's only business-central - where can I find similar page there?

I also tried to connect with REST using following code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        String deploymentId = "com.example.test:test_project:1.0";
        URL baseUrl = new URL("http://localhost:8080/business-central");
        String user = "aswu";
        String password = "uwsa@123";
        RemoteRestRuntimeFactory restSessionFactory = new RemoteRestRuntimeFactory(
                deploymentId, baseUrl, user, password);
        System.out.println("Is RemoteRestRuntimeFactory created : "
            + (restSessionFactory != null));
        RemoteRuntimeEngine runtimeEngine = restSessionFactory
                .newRuntimeEngine();
        KieSession kieSession = runtimeEngine.getKieSession();
        System.out.println("Is KieSession obtained : " + (kieSession != null));
        kieSession.startProcess("test-project.test-process");
    }
}
```

I've got then the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error invoking StartProcessCommand via REST (http://localhost:8080/business-central/rest/runtime/com.example.test:test_project:1.0/execute):

<html><head><title>JBoss Web/7.2.2.Final-redhat-1 - JBWEB000064: Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 404 - Could not find resource for relative : /runtime/com.example.test:test_project:1.0/execute of full path: http://localhost:8080/business-central/rest/runtime/com.example.test:test_project:1.0/execute</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>JBWEB000309: type</b> JBWEB000067: Status report</p><p><b>JBWEB000068: message</b> <u>Could not find resource for relative : /runtime/com.example.test:test_project:1.0/execute of full path: http://localhost:8080/business-central/rest/runtime/com.example.test:test_project:1.0/execute</u></p><p><b>JBWEB000069: description</b> <u>JBWEB000124: The requested resource is not available.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>JBoss Web/7.2.2.Final-redhat-1</h3></body></html>
at org.kie.services.client.api.command.AbstractRemoteCommandObject.executeRestCommand(AbstractRemoteCommandObject.java:342)
at org.kie.services.client.api.command.AbstractRemoteCommandObject.execute(AbstractRemoteCommandObject.java:110)
at org.drools.core.command.impl.CommandBasedStatefulKnowledgeSession.startProcess(CommandBasedStatefulKnowledgeSession.java:232)
at org.drools.core.command.impl.CommandBasedStatefulKnowledgeSession.startProcess(CommandBasedStatefulKnowledgeSession.java:223)
at pl.worc.pwr.student.vl.workflow.brms.Test.main(Test.java:30)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you had installed BRMS, in authoring environment, not execution one.So you cannot run the process on it.

https://community.jboss.org/thread/240717

Answer (score 0):

can you try changing the URL in your code to: "http://:8080/business-central-server" ? without the <>

Comment: Thank you for the replay. I could not connect with it and I got to know why.

The business-central-server is the part of BRMS 5, but not BRMS 6. My problem was that new version of BRMS have no execution environment, so the REST API was limited to the part connected with repositories. It works on BPM Suite, which has the execution environment.